# Apply scope to an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in a controller:

```
@apples = Apple.includes(:oranges)
```

How can I apply a scope on the oranges?

I've tried everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@apples = Apple.joins(:oranges) & Orange.scope
```

Take a look at the last example from [this blog post](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html).